# Lambda Function in VPC has no Internet Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation

My Lambda function has access to other resources in the VPC, but once it attempts to make a request out to the Internet it will timeout. I have the following:

- Two private subnets
- A Route Table that routes 0.0.0.0/0 to the Internet Gateway.
- A couple ACL Rules and a Lambda Security Group

Any help would be helpful. Here are my CF Templates:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: VPC Stack
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Subnet1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Subnet2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1e'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  AttachGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  RouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Route:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  NetworkAcl:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  InboundHTTPNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '100'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allowAWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: VPC Stack
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Subnet1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Subnet2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1e'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  AttachGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  RouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  Route:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  NetworkAcl:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  InboundHTTPNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '100'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '80'
        To: '80'
  InboundSSHNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '101'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '22'
        To: '22'
  InboundResponsePortsNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '102'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '1024'
        To: '65535'
  OutBoundNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '103'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'true'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociation2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties: 
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          GroupDescription: Access to Lambda functions
          SecurityGroupIngress:
            - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
              IpProtocol: -1
         SecurityGroupEgress:
            - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
              IpProtocol: -1
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC ID
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-VpcId"
  Subnet1:
    Description: Subnet ID 1
    Value: !Ref Subnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-SubnetID1"
  Subnet2:
    Description: Subnet ID 2
    Value: !Ref Subnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-SubnetID2"      
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Description: Access to Lambda functions
    Value: !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "LambdaSecurityGroup"      
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '80'
        To: '80'
  InboundResponsePortsNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '102'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '1024'
        To: '65535'
  OutBoundNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '103'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'true'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociation2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAcl
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties: 
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          GroupDescription: Access to Lambda functions
          SecurityGroupIngress:
            - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
              IpProtocol: -1
          SecurityGroupEgress:
            - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
              IpProtocol: -1
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC ID
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-VpcId"
  Subnet1:
    Description: Subnet ID 1
    Value: !Ref Subnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-SubnetID1"
  Subnet2:
    Description: Subnet ID 2
    Value: !Ref Subnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-SubnetID2"      
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Description: Access to Lambda functions
    Value: !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "LambdaSecurityGroup"
```

CF Template 2:

```
Lambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: "index.handler"
      Environment: 
        Variables:
          Environment: !Ref Environment
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: "nodejs6.10"
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !ImportValue "LambdaSecurityGroup"
        SubnetIds:
          - !ImportValue "Portal-SubnetID1"
          - !ImportValue "Portal-SubnetID2"
      Code: 
        S3Bucket: !Ref BaseS3Bucket
        S3Key:  
          !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref TemplatePath
              - '/'
              - !Ref Environment
              - '/Quick-Links/build-output.zip'
```

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a Lambda function inside a VPC, the Lambda function will only receive a private IP address. It will not receive a public IP address.

In order for any AWS server to access the public internet through an Internet Gateway, it must:

1. have a public IP address, and
2. be in a public subnet (ie. a subnet with direct access to an Internet Gateway)

Since your Lambda function does not have that public IP address, it cannot access the internet, even though it's in a public subnet.

To resolve this, you must execute your Lambda function in a private subnet. This being a subnet that:

1. does not have direct access to an Internet Gateway, and
2. directs all outward connections through a NAT instance or NAT gateway

Answer (score 3):

You need to route through a NAT instance if you want Lambda’s to communicate with the internet.

Add two more subnets and a NAT gateway to your existing VPC subnets. Then, set the route table in your new subnet to route the internet through the NAT.

Comment: @DominickPiganell - to clarify why *Chris* says you need two more subnets: when a subnet is routed to an Internet Gateway it is a _public_ subnet. Private subnets do not route through an IGW, but may route through a NAT Gateway (which is different from a NAT Instance).